# Most scenic route between Hartford, CT and Montreal

Tags: usa, canada, montreal, quebec, connecticut

I'm going to be driving from Hartford to Montreal in June. According to Google Maps there are two possible routes: the 87 via Albany, NY or the 91/89 through Vermont. Both routes take about the same amount of time. What scenery can I expect along each route?

Comment: I have edited your question to be objective, rather than asking for opinions, in hopes that it won't be closed.  It should still answer your question fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of preference, the Vermont route is a little bit faster, though a little plain in my opinion. I prefer the NY route because the scenery varies, you get to see mountains (Adirondacks) and lakes, the road isn't just a straight stretch and there are plenty of rest areas and service stops. The 87 becomes the 15 in Quebec which is a highway. Those have higher maximum speed limits than regular provincial roads and I'm a little embarrassed to say, maintained more regularly.

Also, and this is entirely subjective, it's my impression that the crossing at the NY border is more efficient.

Comment: I mostly agree with this, though with one caveat: going through Vermont makes it *exceptionally* easy to make a brief pit stop in Burlington at The Alchemist to buy a case of Heady Topper, the #1 Rated Beer in the World. If you're into IPA's, it's a hard argument to ignore. (You could also stop off at several other Vermont brewers that are literally along the highway and make a tour of it.)

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer for the Québec part of it since I'm a local:
The 15 will be much quicker but [route 133](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_Route_133) which we call *Route des Patriotes* here is very nice and you could take it up to Saint-Jean-sur-Richelieu if coming from Vermont.

And try not to get to Montreal at traffic hour, it can take quite a while to get on the island.